# Gitflow + Forking workflow (on Stash)?

Tags: git, git-flow, git-fork, bitbucket-server

Is it possible to use Gitflow on top of a forking mindset?  If so, how would you do things like create a local feature branch, push it to your origin and then pull request it?  Would you pull request a branch to make it available to others?  I'm especially interested in how this works with Atlassian Stash.

Thanks!

Comment: How would `git-flow` conflict with forking?

Comment: I just mean - how would it work?  So, the upstream would have develop and master branches...  Where do the feature/release/bugfix branches, etc go?  In individual forks?  How do you collaborate?  Can a branch created on an individual fork be pull requested into the upstream?  ...  Do my questions make sense? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stash developer here.

I think what Chris was getting at with his question is that technically forking, or not, should have no impact on gitflow. The feature/bugfix branches can either live in the main repository or on a fork. It doesn't, however, make sense for the release branches to really live in forks because it's not something you generally want to have diverging copies of (although you may well raise a bugfix pull request from a fork into a release branch).

Generally with features and bugfixes, if you're using either forking *or* just using branches in a single repository, then creating a pull request to the upstream repository is the best means of signalling your intent to merge into the dev/master branches, which then becomes an appropriate place for code review and conversation about the changes.

When you say 'collaborate' on a branch do you mean have multiple people working at the same time, or just code reviews. Assuming the former then there's nothing stopping you from having a personal fork where you have granted permissions to someone else and you either both push to the same branch, or you create pull requests *between* your forks, and then eventually back to the upstream repository. Whatever you like.

Specifically regarding Stash, there are some answers here which might give you an idea of how Stash interacts with GitFlow:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/220237/stash-branching-model-vs-git-flow

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/165443/git-flow-with-stash

Just some food for thought on forking vs branches - the Stash team mostly uses a single repository with bugfix/feature branches. There are two reasons for this.

1. It makes having branch builds in Bamboo (or your CI of choice) much easier, at least for now. Bamboo can poll that repository, look for branches matching a regex and create a build for each one without any manual intervention. It gets a little more complicated with forks.
2. Visibility within the team - you can automatically see what people are working on without having to go to Stash or track each personal fork.

Forking is perfect when you don't have trust between two parties or need some form of enforced isolation, like open source. However, if you're in an organisation where you "trust" everyone on your team I would argue that having a single repository makes things much easier/streamlined. Just my 2c.

I hope that helps?

Comment: Yeah, that helps a ton.  Just one question, here:  is it possible to do pull requests without forking? (It sounded like it it based on your answer.)  How would that work?  (Thanks!)

Comment: Exactly the same. You push a bugfix or hotfix branch to the main/top repository, and then when you create a pull request both the source and target branch (usually master or a release branch) will be in the same repository rather than the source being a fork. The fork is really only useful for isolation/permissions. :)

Comment: So, workflow in that scenario would be like this:  Developer checks out feature branch, does work, commits and pushes.  Then developer would pull request from feature branch into develop branch, for example?

Comment: Yep. And you can push to either the main repository, to your fork (or someone elses). The pull request will work the same from either of those locations. Welcome to DVCS. :)

Comment: I should add that none of this has to do with Gitflow, that's just a sensible naming and branching convention.

Comment: Gotcha...  but with forking, you might gain the benefit of pushing to your origin branch, and then pull requesting to the same branch in upstream?

Comment: Sure, if you want the same name. On Stash team we name branch each after a JIRA ticket and a short description, just as feature/STASH-1234-branch-filtering or bugfix/STASH-5678-pr-scroll-bug. The target branch could be a long-running feature branch, or more commonly just master. If we were pull requesting from the fork as 'master' to 'master' it wouldn't be very descriptive and you often have more than one PR open at once. *Shrug* It's really whatever works best for your workflow/team. :)

Comment: So, basically, you only do pull requests (code review) when a feature is finished or a bug has been fixed?

Comment: Well yes and no. We use pull requests for _everything_, based on a single unit of work. For features we will almost always create an epic (in JIRA) and then break it up into small stories, each of which will have a (small) PR. Ideally we can merge each to master, so we can dogfood sooner rather than later, but for some complicated features we have an epic branch to avoid breaking master. It depends on the feature.

Comment: So, why even branch at all if you are rolling everything right away into master?

Comment: Isolation. We have branch builds that run against every feature/bugfix branch, and they need to be green before we merge, along with approval from at least one (or two) people from the team. Why wouldn't you branch?

Comment: No, my question isn't why you would branch - because I think branching is essential.  My question is why you are integrating immediately.  Why dirty master - or whatever line you merge into - before the feature you are working on is complete?

Comment: (Did that make sense?)

Comment: Oh right. Two reasons. 1. The cost of maintaining a feature branch can be higher, and may result in ongoing merge conflicts. 2. The sooner it gets on master the faster and longer we can dogfood it. Some features are more difficult to do incrementally, especially if they involve database changes, and we may not merge in those cases. We did that for repository hooks for example. As I've said - it really depends, one size doesn't fit all.

Comment: I'm personally of the opinion we should be doing even _less_ long running features, but there's no doubt it requires more up-front investment, such as feature flags and more code paths. I will (generally) prefer that pain over having long-running feature branches, but that's just me.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of having release branches that start when development starts for the release. Sometimes we have more than one release happening at once, and often features get shucked or added to given releases at different points.  Like, we may start a feature release, and then decide that we need to have a maintenance release before we move forward with the feature release, so it would be good to have branches for those release branches.

Comment: Go for it. Just keep in mind it's a tradeoff, the cost of maintaining a long-running feature branches vs the complexity of having multiple unfinished features on a single branch. Pick your poison. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think in terms of using git-flow with a fork one of the questions that's bound to come up is the usual: if tracking upstream (which is desirable), where do the upstream changes go? Indeed, that was the first thing I thought of when I stumbled across this thread a few moments ago.

The thing is, when you eventually "git flow feature finish feature/whatever" it will end up merging back into your fork develop branch. That's all good. But then eventually you will get to "git flow release start X.X.X" and "git flow release finish X.X.X" and that will result in a merge into your fork master. If you have been blindly pulling upstream changes directly into master, then your fork may begin to diverge from your intended goals for maintaining the fork in the first place. What you really want to do, I think, is cherry pick from upstream.

In which case, the normal method of tracking upstream applies: create an "upstream" branch and set it to track upstream. No, git-flow won't do anything with that "upstream" branch, but then just because you are using git-flow it doesn't mean you can't create additional branches. Or use other features of git in general that git-flow doesn't necessarily do anything special with.